# Can "Could" or "Would" be used after comma?

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure

"I need to go to the restroom in just a moment, could you please take care of my kid?"

Does this sentence sound right?

Thanks.

Comment: It's semantically *credible* in a somewhat contrived context, but ***in** just a moment* doesn't sound at all likely to me. You probably meant ***for** just a moment*. The presence or absence of a comma has no bearing on the ***could / would / will / might / etc.*** choice.

Comment: It's a comma splice in a formal sentence; but this is spoken language where what one would hear is a brief pause.  A semi-colon or a dash or even a colon would work in printed dialog.

Answer (score 1):

"Could" or "would" after a comma is fine, but this is a run-on sentence that should be "I need to go to the restroom in just a moment. Could you please take care of my kid?"

At least an example of when "could" and "would" can follow a comma is any case where they begin a main clause that is preceded by a dependent clause. "If I'm still sick tomorrow, could you please bring me dinner?" A main clause that begins with "could" is treated no differently from any other main clause.

Comment: You can also use "could" or "would" after a comma if you're talking about the word itself. An example being, " However, while the letter l was historically pronounced in the latter two, could never had an l sound in it."

Answer (score 0):

Beyond the 'comma usage', it is good to note how "could" is a word more akin to 'ability' versus "would" which is a request. Could this person watch a child...almost certainly. Would they watch a child is an entirely different matter. In a 'pinch' however a possible way to make such a request might be to say "Could you, would you please watch my child while I use the facilities?"